# Is Aurora Serverless v1 still available

Tags: aws-appsync, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to use and RDS with AppSync using this tutorial https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/relational/ but it appears to need Data API, only available on Serverless v1.

I'm not able to find this option when creating my database.

I tried different versions of MySQL Aurora, but none showed me serverless v1.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html) to create Serverless V1 instances.

Comment: Hello, this is what I tried, but it is stated that Serverless1 is available with vers 5.7.2 but this option is not shown here : 

![AWS Console screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/VsjXhGt)

Comment: MySQL 5.7.2 is a milestone release and it is very old. See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html). Therefore, you may not see this version anymore. Please use the supported version instead.

Comment: Thanks, but none of the supported version offers Serverless v1, and so no AppSync capabilities. Have you any clue ?

Comment: I don't understand when you say "none of the supported version offers Serverless V1". MySQL 5.7 is supported by Serverless V1. See this [AWS documentation for supported versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraMySQLReleaseNotes/AuroraMySQL.Updates.ServerlessUpdates.html).

Comment: When I create a new database, the only versions I can choose are the following :
Aurora (MySQL 5.7) 2.07.9
Aurora (MySQL 5.7) 2.11.1
Aurora (MySQL 5.7) 2.11.2
Aurora (MySQL 5.7) 2.11.3
Aurora MySQL 2.12.0 (compatible with MySQL 5.7.40)
Aurora MySQL 3.01.0 (compatible with MySQL 8.0.23)
Aurora MySQL 3.01.1 (compatible with MVSOL 8.0.23)
Aurora MySQL 3.02.0 (compatible with MySQL 8.0.23)
Aurora MySQL 3.02.1 (compatible with MySOL 8.0.23) and so on, but none of them alows me to choose Serverless V1.

Answer (score 0):

Right now (2023-08-29), you have to use the create-db-cluster command in the AWS CLI, specifying version 2.08.3. See the CLI example on this doc page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html